# Are there small-sample cases where we can approximate the distribution of the Wald statistic better than with the Normal/Chi-squared distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, chi-squared-test, binomial-distribution, asymptotics, wald-test

In my specific case, I'm referring to the parameter estimates of a binomial regression (regardless of whether we are estimating risk ratios or odds ratios). Can the problem of divergence of the Wald statistic from the Normal distribution be solved by using different distributions? In particular, I'm thinking of the t distribution (or the F one, in the case of multiple parameters). I understand that, with a binomial outcome, the uncertainty is different from the case of linear regression (since only one parameter has to be estimated  given that the variance depends on the probability); nevertheless, even under the null hypothesis, there's still uncertainty (related to the values of the other regression parameters).
I know that, for the cases where the Wald test underperforms, the usual suggestion is to use a Likelihood-Ratio test; nevertheless, since I want to compare results with the ones from a model with multiple-imputation, I'd like to avoid id.

Comment: Bootstrapping the Wald statistic might work if your sample isn't too small.